# How to dynamically allocate a struct and it's TCHAR member array with calloc?

Tags: dynamic-allocation

I can setup a structure easy enough on the stack:

```
struct sArray
{
TCHAR sName[512];
};
struct sArray sKeys[2048] = {0};
```

But that is using way too much of the stack space.

Instead, I want to put it all on the heap, so I came up with this:

```
struct sArray
{
    TCHAR *sName;
};
struct sArray *sKeys = (sArray *) calloc(2048, sizeof(sArray));
```

How do I dynamically allocate memory for the sName? I tried this and it doesn't compile:

```
TCHAR *sKeys[0].sName = (TCHAR *) calloc(512,sizeof(TCHAR));
```

I'm really overlooking something here. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: I tried this: 
 `struct sArray
 {
  TCHAR *sName; // Dynamically sized
 }*sKeys[2048]; 
 for (DWORD i=0;i<2048;i++)
  sKeys[i] = (sArray *) calloc(1,sizeof(sArray)); 
`

Should I do the calloc to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
sKeys[0].sName = (TCHAR *) calloc(512,sizeof(TCHAR));
```

(No TCHAR * in front)

Comment: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'sKeys' is being used without being initialized.

Comment: Did you take out the calloc? If you do the initial `struct sArray *sKeys = (sArray *) calloc(2048, sizeof(sArray));`, you should not be getting a run-time error. BTW, I assume the language is C? Is that right? 'cos if it's C++, you are going about this all wrong, and should use `new`.

Comment: Yeah, I mistakenly took out calloc. It's C++, so how do I use the `new`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <cstring>

typedef struct MyData {
    TCHAR processPath[ 32 ];
} MYDATA, *PMYDATA;

int main()
{
    PMYDATA pData = (PMYDATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(MYDATA));
    strcpy(pData->processPath, TEXT ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe")); 
}
```

I used this command to compile:

```
"C:\MinGW64\bin\g++.exe" -o ThreadExample.exe ThreadExample.cpp -lpsapi
```